# Application compiled with AnyCPU can't run on 32bit Windows10

Tags: c#, .net-core, 32bit-64bit

I have compiled my very simple C# WinForms app on a 64bit system, with DotNet 7.0.2, VS2022 with this configuration:

[image]

Here is the app:

[image]

It doesn't do anything, just a Form with a Button.

Now, when I deploy it to a 32bit machine (Windows 10), I got this error message:

[image]

I'm the *software publisher* - what can I do? I'm pretty sure it's related somehow to the 32/64 bitness of the system.

"*Any CPU*" shall be the most suitable for running it on both 32/64 bit machines, isn't it?

For the target, I have installed the ".NET 7.0 Desktop Runtime (v7.0.2) x86" From here (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0):

[image]

And it's installed on the target system:

[image]

Comment: "Any CPU" basically just means "Whatever the machine I'm working on supports", unless the project is a class library in which case it will support both (depending on which one the process that is loading it is running with). If you want it to work on both 32-bit and 64-bit machines, you need to explicitly set it to 32-bit.

Comment: Your linked answer does not seem to say this.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError It does, but it's only talking about class libraries. I'll just remove it because I basically already restated it in the comment.

Comment: Any compiler warning?

Comment: Please investigate/clarify what .Net 7 apps you can run on that x86 Win10.

Comment: Curiosity: Why are you supporting 32bit? That flavor of windows is slated for EOL in 2025. It's also not well supported even currently.

Comment: Try checking/unchecking "Prefer 32-bit" flag

Comment: Also has the 32bit machine had the [.net 7.0 desktop x86 runtime installed](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-desktop-7.0.2-windows-x86-installer)?

Comment: @AndersonPimentel: not a single compiler warning (0 error, 0 warning, 0 info). And in VS2022, there is no such thing "Prefer 32-bit"

Comment: @Mgetz: sure! I had installed it from the official pages (filename: windowsdesktop-runtime-7.0.2-win-x86.exe)

Comment: @HansPassant: sure. Platform target is "Any CPU" in there too.

Comment: The screenshot shows the solution platform, that's not what determines the bitness.  For .NET5+ you need a .exe file that can run on a 32-bit machine.  Used to be easy on the legacy framework, but it isn't anymore in .NETCore.  The .exe file is the host, its job is to load and initialize the CLR.  It is a purely unmanaged executable, you'll get the 64-bit flavor of it if you ask for "AnyCPU".  Not "any cpu" anymore, the only true AnyCPU is using dotnet.exe.  To get the right flavor you need to force generation of a 32-bit host.  Project > Properties > Build > General > Platform target = x86.

Comment: Anyhow can I get an "AnyCPU" flavored launcher exe?

Comment: As noted, start the program with dotnet.exe

Comment: 32-bit exe runs fine on 64-bit Windows.  Every ap in `c:\program files (x86)` is 32-bit.  You do lose access to RAM though -- a max of 2 GB or 3 GB depending on whether Net sets /LARGEADDRESSAWARE

Comment: Can I create a build config to build both a 32bit version and both the AnyCPU version of the project?

Comment: @HansPassant: dotnet myapp.dll works fine, however if I create a shortcut for this, it has a console window constantly, while the app runs, which makes it unusable.